# Deleting nullable field is deleting related objects

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

I have a `Tournament` model with related `Standings`:

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    standings = models.ForeignKey('Standings', blank=True, null=True)
```

I just did the following:

```
standings = Standings.objects.get(pk=pk)
standings.delete()
```

And it deleted the related tournament as well. This should not have happened, since `standings` is a nullable field.

Why did it happen and what can I do to prevent this from happening again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django 1.8 defaults to [`CASCADE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete):

> When an object referenced by a `ForeignKey` is deleted, Django by default emulates the behavior of the `SQL` constraint `ON DELETE CASCADE` and also deletes the object containing the `ForeignKey`.

To change that behavior, you should add the `on_delete` argument (mandatory as of Django 2.x) as follows:

```
standings = models.ForeignKey(
    'Standings', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```